# Fast algorithm for detecting community structure in networks in igraph

Tags: igraph

I would like to know if the algorithm for finding communities based on via modularity-based clustering, published by Newman in 2004: "Fast algorithm for detecting community structure in networks" is available in the igraph-R package, if it is not implemented, is there a easy way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modMax package on CRAN has a function called "greedy" that implements an algorithm which will give identical results.  The method was presented in a 2004 paper by Clauset, Newman, and Moore ("Finding community structure in very large networks") as a modification to improve the speed of the original algorithm in the paper you have listed.